# How to send login toking swift to another view

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a new application in swift, I use company API to login using .post but how can I sand to another views? I need to authentication in another view to access .get...

My Login Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let emailText: String? = emailField.text
    let passwordText: String? = passwordField.text

    APIAuthentication.loginWith(email: emailText!, password: passwordText!) { (response, error, cache) in

        if response != nil {

        } else if let error = error {
            if let urlResponse = error.urlResponse, urlResponse.statusCode == 401 {
                // logout user
            } else if let responseObject = error.responseObject as? [String: Any], let _ = responseObject["error_message"] {
                // show errorMessage
            } else {
                // show error.originalError.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Request API

```
struct Constants {
    static let baseURL = URL(string: "xxxx/api/v1/users/auth/")!
    static let apiPath = ""
    static let authenticationHeaders = ["access-token", "client", "uid"]
    static let authenticationHeadersDefaultsKey = "authenticationHeaders"
}
```

APIAuthentication

```
struct User: Mappable {
init(mapper: Mapper) { }
```

}

class APIAuthentication: APIRequest {

```
@discardableResult
static func loginWith(email: String, password: String, callback: ResponseBlock<User>?) -> APIAuthentication {

    let request = APIAuthentication(method: .post, path: "sign_in", parameters: ["email": email, "password": password], urlParameters: nil, cacheOption: .networkOnly) { (response, error, cache) in

        if let error = error {
            callback?(nil, error, cache)
        } else if let response = response as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User(dictionary: response)
            callback?(user, nil, cache)
        }
    }
    request.shouldSaveInCache = false
    request.makeRequest()

    return request
}
```

}

Comment: You can send data to other view by calling Segue and passing the relevant data or by making a Singleton object and save data their and later, access it anywhere...

Comment: how can I obtain the relevant ? this case token? how can I do that? I knew in swift :/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data between different ViewControllers with a segue. Please try to implement the code below

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let yourVc = segue.destination as? YourViewController
    yourVc?.YOUR_VARIABLE = VariableWithDataFromCurrentVc
}
```

Comment: And then call performSegue(with: identifier, sender: Any?) function to achieve that ...

Comment: in this case, VariableWithDataFromCurrentVc is my token access? but, how can I storage that?

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults if you will need to persist data. Please accept my answer :-).